# finding the limit of two sequences

Tags: real-analysis

So I have a question that asks if {s$_n$} and {t$_n$} are two sequences in $\Bbb R$, $\lim s_n = \infty$ and $\limsup t_n = -\infty$. Prove that $\lim(s_n t_n) = -\infty$.

I'm having trouble trying to put this down in words. I know that if the limit of the suprema approaches negative infinity, then anything multiplied with the positive values of s$_n$ will be negative. Can anyone give me a hint on how I should start? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Start by writing the definition of $\lim s_n = \infty$.

**Hint:** Continue by writing the definition of $\lim \sup t_n = - \infty$.

**Hint:** Write the definition of $\lim (s_n t_n) = - \infty$.

**Hint:** Now, combine the first two, and show that you get the third.

Comment: For the second hint, if lim sup $t_n$ is =$-$ $\infty$, does that mean everything in the set is negatively infinite? How does that work?

Comment: @rawrPanda No. The sequence $-1, -2, -3, -4, \ldots -n$ has a lim sup of $-\infty$. The sup of $X_{N \geq n}$ is clearly $-n$, and the limit of this sequence is $-\infty$.